# Sending automatic emails to specific email addresses once rows are edited in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm new to g-scripts and facing some issues in coming up with the code for the below. My goal is:

- Want to send an automatic email to specific people once the information in any of the rows in the google sheet are edited.(note: the range is the whole sheet)
- For each row in the google sheet, there's an email address next to it (under a new column) which specifies the person this automatic email should be sent to.
- Can the changes be compiled once per day and sent via 1 email per email address?

Thank you in advance for your help.
Currently, this is my code:

function onEdit(e){

```
var rows = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheet1").getRange(30000,30).getValue();
var headerRow = rows.shift();
var editedRow = e.range.getRow();

var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Template1.html");
template.headerRow = headerRow;
template.editedRow = editedRow;
template.rows = rangeValues;

var html = template.evaluate().getContent();
```

function sendEmails(){

```
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheet1").activate();
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var lr=ss.getLastRow();

//getting email body:
var sheet2Text = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheet2").getRange(1,1).getValue();

// Logger.log(emailText);
var quotaLeft  = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
Logger.log(quotaLeft);
  if((lr-1)>quotaleft){
    Browser.msgBox("You have"+quotaLeft+"left & you're trying to send"+(lr-1)+"emails. Emails not sent");
  } else{
    for(var i=2; i<lr; i++){
      var currentEmail = ss.getRange(i,26).getValue();
    var currentClientName = ss.getRange(i,1).getValue();
    var currentTeamName = ss.getRange(i,27).getValue();
  
    var messageBody = sheet2Text.replace("{name}",currentTeamName);
    var subjectLine = "notification on" + currentClientName + "process list", html;

    MailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail, subjectLine, messageBody);
    //26 is the column number that contains the emails in the google sheet

  } //closing the for loop

} // closing the else loop
```

} // closing the function sendEmails

} // closing the onEdit function

Comment: The trigger `onEdit()` should be installed if you want to make it to send emails https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Comment: Thank you, the below is actually triggering an email now, but its doing that for my email only. How can i make it send emails that are specified at each row in the sheet?

Comment: function onSheetEdit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var rows = sheet.getRangeByName("NamedRange1").getValues();
  var headerRow = rows.shift(); 
  var editedRow = e.range.getRow();
  
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Template1.Html");
  template.headerRow = headerRow;
  template.editedRow = editedRow;
  template.rows = rows;
  
  var html = template.evaluate().getContent();
  
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "xxx@xxx.com",
    subject: "Test 2 gscript",
    htmlBody: html
  });
}

Comment: Not sure if understand the problem. Do you want to send emails to different addresses? Probably it will work if you change `to: "xxx@xxx.com"` to `currentEmail` (it's need to define the `currentEmail` variable of course, as it's in your code sample in the question)